# Multiple Screenshots of Url with Puppeteer giving Error: target should exist before targetInfoChanged at Object.assert

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I have a list of 50 plus urls I'm looping through, the only being screenshot is the first url, then it breaks and says: " Error: target should exist before targetInfoChanged
at Object.assert ---- ";

below is the code.

```
 const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    const data = [
    {"website_link":"https://www.palnetsolutions.com",
        'site_name':'palnetsolutions.com'   
    },
    {"website_link":"https://oneziko.com",
        'site_name':'oneziko.com'   
    },
    {"website_link":"https://www.isampo.com",
        'site_name':'isampo.com'    
    },
    ---- more data
    ];
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  for(const x of data){
    await page.goto(x.website_link, { waitUntill: 'networkidle2'});
    await page.screenshot({path: `${x.site_name}.jpg`});
    console.log(`${x.site_name} Done` );
  }
  await browser.close();
})();



when I run this, the first url is getting capture.
Your help is highly appreciated.
```

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code and it works fine, it creates a screenshot of every website in the data array.

If that code doesn't work for you, then there is probably a problem in your Puppeteer setup.

I suspect that you are using an older version of Puppeteer or you are using Puppeteer-core with your own supplied chrome browser.

Comment: I discovered the challenge is  capturing more than 10 urls. 
If i put 10 urls, it works out fine, but 11 plus, those error are coming and can't figure it out.
My solution was to use #puppeteer-cluster. [https://github.com/thomasdondorf/puppeteer-cluster]

Comment: Otherwise, thanks for giving me feedback.